# Shuffle divs with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm building an app with ionic and i search a way to shuffle divs each time the user loads the screen. I don't use ng-repeat, is there an other way to reorder some divs on a refresh?

Any help much appreciated!

One div looks like this:

```
<div class="barock center">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>BAROCK</h1>
    <h4>Bester Kaffee der Stadt</h4>
    <img src="img/home/open.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

And I would like to reorder all of them.

Comment: Would it be possible to share show code so we can see how you are building your page?

Comment: you haven't given enough information to offer a full solution, but from what you are describing, these divs aren't generated by angular, so angular isn't going to be involved in this shuffle operation, unless you write a custom directive to take over rendering these items.  You are free to use plain javascript or any other javascript library to do this task, however, and it shouldn't affect angular.

Comment: Could you give me a hint how i could reorder them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just come up with this solution, and haven't really worked on it, just to give you idea!

Here we have a directive:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
.controller("MainController", function(){});

app.directive('reorderDiv', function ($compile) {
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {

        function shuffle(array) {
            var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

            // While there remain elements to shuffle...
            while (0 !== currentIndex) {

                // Pick a remaining element...
                randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
                currentIndex -= 1;

                // And swap it with the current element.
                temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
                array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
                array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
            }

            return array;
        }
        elem.on('click', function () {

            console.log('called');
            var divs = elem.find('div');
            console.log(divs);

            divs = shuffle(divs);
            var content = $compile(divs)(scope);
            elem.append(content);
        })
    }
})
```

and here is the template:

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <div reorder-div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

what does this directive do? It just gathers all divs inside the element which I have applied my directive and shuffle those divs, shuffle them and change the , use `$compile` service to compile it against the `scope`, and set the content of outer div to the shuffled compiled temple.

If you click on outer dive, you will see that its content are shuffled.

Comment: How could i change it so that it's running when the page loads? Now it's on element click. Thank you :)

Comment: @olivier I don't know :). have you tried to put `click` handler directly into link function?

Answer (score 0):

```
   function shuffleChildren(parentID) {
     var id = "#" + parentId;
     var parent = angular.element(id);
     var divs = parent.children();
     while (divs.length) {
       parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
     }
   }
}
```

This will shuffle the children of any div with id parentID that you pass in.

You could use it as such:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        shuffleChildren(parentID);
    });
```

Adapted from: http://jsfiddle.net/C6LPY/2/